# Application error after successfully deploying heroku app

Tags: node.js, heroku

Error:

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail

These are the logs :

$ heroku logs --tail  --app boiling-springs-32990

»   Warning: heroku update available from 7.54.0 to 7.59.1.
2021-12-20T20:45:07.413154+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-12-20T20:45:07.413154+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-12-20T20:45:07.413155+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
2021-12-20T20:45:07.413156+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
2021-12-20T20:45:07.413156+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
2021-12-20T20:45:07.413156+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
{
2021-12-20T20:45:07.413157+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'EADDRINUSE',
2021-12-20T20:45:07.413158+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -98,
2021-12-20T20:45:07.413158+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'listen',
2021-12-20T20:45:07.413158+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '::',
2021-12-20T20:45:07.413159+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 57582
2021-12-20T20:45:07.413159+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-12-20T20:45:07.565451+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-20T20:45:07.642637+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-21T02:29:16.793339+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-21T02:29:19.299053+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706025+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:292
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706035+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706035+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706036+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706036+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::51735
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706036+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706036+00:00 app[web.1]: at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706037+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.listen (net.js:1452:7)
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706037+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.listen (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706037+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object. (/app/app.js:136:5)
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706038+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706038+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706038+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706038+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706039+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706039+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706039+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706040+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
{
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706040+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'EADDRINUSE',
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706040+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -98,
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706040+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'listen',
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706041+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '::',
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706041+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 51735
2021-12-21T02:29:20.706041+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-12-21T02:29:20.886687+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-21T02:29:21.102194+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-21T08:05:34.066199+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-21T08:05:36.829412+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370913+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:292
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370930+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370931+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370931+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370932+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8362
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370932+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370932+00:00 app[web.1]: at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370932+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.listen (net.js:1452:7)
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370933+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.listen (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370933+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object. (/app/app.js:136:5)
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370933+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370934+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370934+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370934+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370935+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370935+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370935+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370935+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370935+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'EADDRINUSE',
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370936+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -98,
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370936+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'listen',
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370936+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '::',
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370936+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 8362
2021-12-21T08:05:38.370936+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-12-21T08:05:38.492434+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-21T08:05:38.579634+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-21T13:49:51.968091+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-12-21T13:49:54.575035+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902743+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:292
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902756+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902757+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902757+00:00 app[web.1]:
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902757+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::32803
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902758+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1318:16)
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902758+00:00 app[web.1]: at listenInCluster (net.js:1366:12)
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902758+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.listen (net.js:1452:7)
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902758+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.listen (/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)2021-12-21T13:49:55.902759+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object. (/app/app.js:136:5)
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902759+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)             )
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902759+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)2021-12-21T13:49:55.902759+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)                  n.js:72:12)
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902760+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902760+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)2021-12-21T13:49:55.902760+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902761+00:00 app[web.1]: at emitErrorNT (net.js:1345:8)
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902761+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902761+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'EADDRINUSE',
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902761+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -98,
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902762+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'listen',
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902762+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '::',
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902762+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 32803
2021-12-21T13:49:55.902762+00:00 app[web.1]: }                                                                       g-springs-32990.herokuapp.com request_id=6f486344-a72c-4563-949b-43489a5ccc8d fwd="157.37.161.38" dyno= connect= servi2021-12-21T13:49:56.025474+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-21T13:49:56.167122+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed                               host=boiling-springs-32990.herokuapp.com request_id=638ee254-72ee-4304-b1da-df654841be55 fwd="157.37.161.38" dyno= con2021-12-21T16:43:35.693385+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=boiling-springs-32990.herokuapp.com request_id=6f486344-a72c-4563-949b-43489a5ccc8d fwd="157.37.161.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https2021-12-21T16:43:36.520550+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=boiling-springs-32990.herokuapp.com request_id=638ee254-72ee-4304-b1da-df654841be55 fwd="157.37.161.38" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Comment: When you call app.listen for the port are you passing process.env.PORT

Comment: Yes I am using environment port as suggested by heroku as well as local port